# How to detect whether a string is present in stdout without affecting the output?

Tags: bash, grep, stdout

I have a program called `my_program` that prints diagnostic message to stdout

I want to detect if the diagnostic messages includes string `"TEST FAILURE"` and if it does, execute some command after the program is done.

The closest answer I have found is

```
if [ !my_program | grep "TEST FAILURE" ]
then
some_cmd
fi
```

However this method will silent all the diagnostic messages. I still want the messages to be shown on the stdout. Some suggest first run the program without using `grep`, then execute the program the second time and pipe to `grep`, however my program takes 1 hour to run, I want to avoid running a large program twice.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is a poor choice because the top-voted answer (like the ones here) does not actually answer the question.

Comment: I would have liked to answer but the question is closed: instead check a similar answer I provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681463/1783588

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tee` to send the command's output to both `grep` and your terminal (`/dev/tty`):

```
# Note grep's stdout is redirected to /dev/null
# because we only care about its exit code
if echo foo | tee /dev/tty | grep foo > /dev/null; then
  echo OK
fi
```

From POSIX's [Directory Structure and Devices](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html):

> **`/dev/tty`**
>
> In each process, a synonym for the controlling terminal associated with the process group of that process, if any. It is useful for programs or shell procedures that wish to be sure of writing messages to or reading data from the terminal no matter how output has been redirected. It can also be used for applications that demand the name of a file for output, when typed output is desired and it is tiresome to find out what terminal is currently in use.

It won't help if you want command's output to be redirected to script's standard output, which may not be the terminal.

You could save command's output for further processing, though:

```
# Save output in a variable (or a regular file, a named pipe, etc.)
output="$(echo foo)"

# Dump output to script's stdout
cat <<< "${output}"

# Check if output matches some pattern
if grep foo <<< "${output}" > /dev/null; then
  echo OK
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop in bash may also solve your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

flagfile=/tmp/flagfile.$$.something

my_program | while read line ; do 
    if echo "$line" | grep "TEST FAILURE" 
    then
        touch $flagfile
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done

if [ -f $flagfile ] ; then
    rm -f $flagfile
    some_cmd
fi
```

Note that you cannot use a flag-variable because the while-loop will be executed in a subshell.